# Samsung laptop boot failure and overheating

Tags: windows-10, laptop, overheating

I have a Samsung NP550PC7C-S02UK i7 laptop. initial symptom windows starts and spinning dots in endless cycles and fails to boot to windows login. automatic repair also fails to load. The laptop overheats and "pops" and shuts down. I have tried booting from USB and DVD - same failure to boot issue.
Removed heatsink and fan - clogged so cleaned and replaced thermal paste. The issue still remains.
removed HDD and loaded in a PC - diskcheck fixed some issues. Put back into laptop and still no boot to login, usb, dvd and auto repair fail and still overheats and cuts out???
Anyone experienced this type of fault? I suspect either cpu, gpu damage or even mobo? helpful suggestions please

Comment: When you loaded the hard drive in the pc, did you try booting from it? That would definitely quickly narrow the problem down.

Comment: Could be the power supply, e.g. blown capacitor. See image at https://www.mikerepairscomputers.com/hardware/bad-capacitors-your-computer/